# Como passar parâmetro para um diálogo com PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou chamando um `Dialog` por através de um botão em JSF com PrimeFaces 5.1 
habilitando o `Dialog` através do `onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()"` do botão.

Alguém sabe dizer se é possível passar um parâmetro para o diálogo ?

O que realmente pretendo fazer:
O diálogo `iconeDeProcessamento` é padrão para três botões que chamam `processamentod` diferentes. 
No diálogo tenho o parâmentro `header="#{TA_MB.tituloProcessamento}"` com a *EL* em questão.
Gostaria de mudar o valor da *EL* `TA_MB.tituloProcessamento` para ser apresentado no diálogo.

Ex:

Botão 1 chama o diálogo e mostra como título "Aguarde... Buscando Dados"
Botão 2 chama o diálogo e mostra como título "Aguarde... Calculando"
Botão 3 chama o diálogo e mostra como título "Aguarde... Gravando"

**Codigo do Botão que chama o diálogo**

```
<p:commandButton id="consulta" disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlEntrada}" 
   value="Busca    movimento" 
   actionListener="#{TA_MB.buscarLinhas}" icon="ui-icon-bookmark"
   styleClass="botao-parametro" 
   update="anoMes consulta novarequisicao linhasTA calculoTA gravaTA"
   onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()"
   onsuccess="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').hide()" >
</p:commandButton>
```

**Dialogo**

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="iconeDeProcessamento" modal="true" draggable="false"
 closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="true" appendTo="@(body)"
 header="#{TA_MB.tituloProcessamento}" style="width:20%;height:20%" >

  <p:graphicImage id="progressoGif" value="../resources/img/loader_blue.gif"
  style="width:40%;height:40%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"/>
</p:dialog>
```

**xHtml com as TAGs em questão**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" > 

     <h:outputStylesheet name="/resources/css/estilo.css" library="css" />              

      <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/t_estrutural.xhtml">

            <ui:param name="render_east" value="true" />        
            <ui:param name="render_west" value="false" />
            <ui:param name="headerTitulo" value="Parametros" />

            <ui:define name="titulo">Calcula TA</ui:define>

            <ui:define name="mensagem">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                        <p:button id="btHome" outcome="principal" value="Home" icon="ui-icon-home" styleClass="botao-parametro" />

                            <h:outputLabel value="Ano/Mes:" for="anoMes"/>
                            <p:inputMask disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlEntrada}" id="anoMes" value="#{TA_MB.anoMes}" validatorMessage="Periodo invalido" mask="9999/99" >
                                <f:validateRegex pattern="20[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}" />
                            </p:inputMask>

                            <p:commandButton id="consulta" disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlEntrada}" value="Busca movimento" 
                                     actionListener="#{TA_MB.buscarLinhas}" icon="ui-icon-bookmark"
                                     styleClass="botao-parametro" 
                                     update="anoMes consulta novarequisicao linhasTA calculoTA gravaTA iconeDeProcessamento"
                                     onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()"
                                     onsuccess="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').hide()" >
                                     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{TA_MB.tituloProcessamento}" value="Aguarde... Buscando dados"/>     
                            </p:commandButton>

                            <p:commandButton id="calculoTA" disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlProcessamento}" value="Calcular TA" 
                                     actionListener="#{TA_MB.calcularTA}" icon="ui-icon-bookmark"
                                     styleClass="botao-parametro" 
                                     update="linhasTA"
                                     onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()"
                                     onsuccess="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').hide()" >
                                     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{TA_MB.tituloProcessamento}" value="Aguarde... Calculando"/>     
                            </p:commandButton>

                            <p:commandButton id="gravaTA" disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlProcessamento}" value="Grava TA" 
                                     actionListener="#{TA_MB.gravarTA}" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                                     styleClass="botao-parametro" 
                                     update="linhasTA"
                                     onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()"
                                     onsuccess="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').hide()">
                                     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{TA_MB.tituloProcessamento}" value="Aguarde... Gravando"/>   
                                     <p:confirm header="Confirma ?" message="Confirma gravação dos Dados?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                            </p:commandButton>                                           

                            <p:button id="novarequisicao" disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlProcessamento}" value="Nova Consulta" styleClass="botao-parametro" icon="ui-icon-refresh" outcome="taCalculo"/>                                                                                         

                    </h:panelGrid>

            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="corpo">
                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
                    <!--  ***********************************  Dialogo do progresso   ************************************************* -->
                    <p:dialog id='iconeDeProcessamento' widgetVar="iconeDeProcessamento" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="true" appendTo="@(form)"
                            style="width:20%;height:20%" >
                            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText id="dialogHeader" value="#{TA_MB.tituloProcessamento}" />                            
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:graphicImage id="progressoGif"  value="../resources/img/loader_blue.gif" style="width:40%;height:40%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"/>
                    </p:dialog>
            </ui:define>
      </ui:composition> 

</html>
```

**Complemento. Tentativa utilizando ajax - Também não funcionou.**
**xHTML**

```
<p:commandButton id="consulta" disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlEntrada}" value="Busca movimento" 
         actionListener="#{TA_MB.buscarLinhas()}" icon="ui-icon-bookmark"
         styleClass="botao-parametro" 
         update="anoMes consulta novarequisicao linhasTA calculoTA gravaTA iconeDeProcessamento"
         onsuccess="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').hide()" >
         <p:ajax update="iconeDeProcessamento" onstart="#{TA_MB.mudaTitulo()}" oncomplete="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()">
            <f:param name="titulo" value="Aguarde... Buscando Dados"/>
         </p:ajax>
</p:commandButton>
```

**Managed Bean**

```
public void mudaTitulo(){
    Map<String,String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String titulo = params.get("titulo");
    this.setTituloProcessamento(titulo);
    System.out.printf("------ verifica mudaTitulo() [ %s ] ",getTituloProcessamento());
}
```

Comment: Como você está importando o facelets desse dialog? Está definido em seu template? A minha sugestão é criar um `ui:insert` com o valor a ser definido em cada tela e usar um `ui:define` para definir esse valor, tendo um **default** para caso não haja definição.

Comment: Seria legal incluir o trecho de código onde você declara seu `dialog` na página. Só pra ter uma visão de onde estão o dialog e o botão.

Comment: Estou utilizando o facelets somente na página principal. para o 'p:dialog' não utilizo facelets. Posso tentar com facelets como sugerido, mas como farei a chamada do evento `onstart` do botão?

Comment: Marcelo, como você está chamando o `dialog` direto no cliente, sem fazer uma requisição ao servidor/Bean, a minha sugestão é mudar o título por JavaScript, pegando o `h:outputText ` por id e alterando seu valor. Não é a melhor solução. O mais correto seria invocar o `dialog` sem JavaScript, apenas com o `action` do botão, mas é um gasto atoa de recursos.

Comment: Utilizei muito pouco javaScript para não dizer nada. Tens alguma exemplo?

Comment: Coloca no seu `onstart`: `onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show(); document.getElementById('dialogHeader').innerHTML = 'TITULO_HEADER';"` ou `onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show(); document.querySelector('#dialogHeader').innerHTML = 'TITULO_HEADER';"`

Comment: Também não funcionou. Pelo que pude notar o segundo comando da linha ( apos o ; ) não é executado ou o comando js direto não funciona.

Comment: Podias, para cada botão definir um título no atributo da Managed Bean, e em cada botão atualizar (usando o atributo `update`) a dialog (por ajax). Depois é so exibir a janela no término da execução (usando o atributo `oncomplete`).

Comment: Veja se fiz o que voce sugeriu (complemento) ? 
Mas tambem não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando o botão for acionado você pode mudar o valor da propriedade `#{TA_MB.tituloProcessamento}` 
usando `<f:setPropertyActionListener />` e atualizar um componente que contém o título do diálogo como a seguir:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{TA_MB.buscarLinhas}"
   <!-- atualiza componente do título -->
   update="dialogHeader" 
   onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()"
   onsuccess="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').hide()" >

    <!-- altera propriedade do título -->
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{TA_MB.tituloProcessamento}" value="seuTitulo" />   

</p:commandButton>
```

**Diálogo com título atualizável**

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="iconeDeProcessamento" >
    <f:facet name="header">
        <!-- componente que será atualizado -->
        <h:outputText id="dialogHeader" value="#{TA_MB.tituloProcessamento}" />                           
    </f:facet>
</p:dialog>
```

Obs.: atributo `header` do `<p:dialog>` será sobrescrito com esse `<f:facet name="header>`

Comment: Não funcionou. Coloquei inclusive um 'System.out.printf' no metódo 'buscarLinhas' para ver se o MB estava sendo atualizado, contudo vem em branco.

Comment: Ok. Fiz um um teste aqui vou melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Mesmo com 'f:facet' não funcionou. O 'f:setPropertyActionListener'  não está atualizando a propriedade 'TA_MB.tituloProcessamento'

Comment: Marcelo, essa abordagem não vai funcionar porque está mostrando o `dialog` por javascript. E nesse caso não é feita uma requisição pro servidor e nem a tela é atualizada por AJAX.

Comment: Fazendo a sequencia do botão notei que está mostrando sempre a mensagem do botão anterior. Ou seja o componente é atualizado, mas somente apos o p:dialog ser chamado.